# sql dies on stream of requests

Tags: sql

I need advice about sql code. I have a table in DB and view of this table. In the view I have several fields same as in the table. I do simple request. This request runs in cycle on each number.

```
$number = [1,2,3,4,5...] /*length = 17*/

select `data` from `view` where `datestart` > cast(curdate() as datetime) and `fieldone` = $number
```

it's working perfectly, but if I do this

```
select `data` from `view` where `dateend` > cast(curdate() as datetime) and `fieldone` = $number
```

it's kills the DB and my website have 504, 503, 502 errors

Fields `datestart` and `dateend` have same type of data datetime and both have index.
I need execute this request, and I don't understand why it's not working with same field.
I had tried execute on one number each time and it takes too long, something about 2 - 3 minutes.
Is someone know what I missing?

Comment: Hello friends! -I don't know why, but stackoverflow cuts it from my question ))

Answer (score 0):

If someone searching an answer for same problem. It might help you! )) So, for better search in `sql`, I'm add one field in `where` block and it's help me. My code below.

```
select `data` from `view` where `datasame` = '2021-04-26' and `datestart` > cast(curdate() as datetime) and `fieldone` = $number
```

My table has another field which has same type of data, and it's help some way to speed up my `select`.
That's it! ))